# logout function not working, keeps throwing errors

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have the following code that logs in a user and i want to be able to use the logout function. But for some reason when i go to logout.php it gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: user in /var/www/www.test.com/logout.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to a member function logout() on null in /var/www/www.test.com/logout.php on line 2
```

I have the following code for my index.php

```
<?php
require_once(ROOT . 'include/dbconfig.php');

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    if($_SESSION['type'] = "Admin"){
        $user->redirect(DOMAIN . 'admin/index.php');    
    }else{
        $user->redirect(DOMAIN . 'customer/index.php');
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password))
    {

        if($_SESSION['type'] = "Admin"){

            $user->redirect(DOMAIN . 'admin/index.php');    

        }else{

            $user->redirect(DOMAIN . 'customer/index.php');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "There was an error with the login";
    }

}else{
?>

<html lang="en" class="body-full-height">
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <table>
        <?php
            if(isset($error))
                {
                 ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $error; ?></td>              
                 <?php
                }
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td>Password</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name"username"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name"password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button name="btn-login" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>    
    </body>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

Below is the code for the class.user.php

```
<?php
class USER
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function register($fname,$lname,$uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = MD5($upass);

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);                                        

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }

    public function login($username,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username 
                                        AND password=:password 
                                        AND status = 'active' LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if($userRow['isadmin']){
                    $_SESSION['type']  = "Admin";
                    $_SESSION['fname'] = $userRow['fname'];
                    $_SESSION['uid']   = $userRow['uid'];
                    return true;
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['type']  = "Customer";
                    $_SESSION['fname'] = $userRow['fname'];
                    $_SESSION['uid']   = $userRow['uid'];
                    return true;
                }

            }else{
                return false;   
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['uid']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Below is the code for the logout.php

```
<?php
$user->logout();
?>
```

Comment: You never actually create `$user`

Comment: The $user is created when a user is logged in on index.php

Comment: That variable is not carried over to new pages. PHP maintains no state.